# Oracle query to loop through different records in the table

Tags: oracle

Apologies in advance I do not have a question instead a situation to which I need to find the solution. Trying to explain the setup with the example -

I have the oracle table as follows -

```
ID Name Qty1 Qty2 Qty3 Date
-- ---- ---- ---- ---- -----------
 1 ABC     0    0  -10 4th-May
 1 ABC     5    0   -5 5th-May
 1 ABC     0    0   -5 6th-May
 1 ABC     0    0   -5 7th-May
 1 ABC     0    0  -10 8th-May
 1 ABC     0    5    0 9th May
 1 ABC     0    0    0 10th May
 1 ABC     1    0   15 11th May
 ...
 1 ABC     0    0   10 (100th Day)
```

--- So on till 100 day from today's date.

Basically, for a single ID,Name I have three quantities starting from the current date till 100th day.

First, I need to find the row where the first occurrence of non zero Qty1 or Qty2 happens( In this case 5th-May record).

Next, I need to find the row where the next occurrence of non-zero Qty1 or Qty2 happens( In this case 9th May). Then I will have to find the record preceding this date (in this case 8th-May).

Qty3 will be picked up from this preceding record  that qty will be inserted for the previous occurrence of the date when Qty1 or Qty2 are non-zero.

The resultant data:

```
 ID Name Qty3 Date
 -- ---- ---- --------
  1 ABC   -10 5th-May
  1 ABC   -10 9th-May
  1 ABC    10 11th-May
```

The last non-zero record will have the Qty3 from the 100th day if there are no non-zero records from  the day till 100th day.

Any leads how can I achieve the requirement. I need to find some solution without using cursors or loop.?

Thanks in Advance and apologies for the bad writeup, but really need an answer to this question.

Comment: Why does the 2nd row in your output have `0` for `Qty3`? Shouldn't it be `-10` from the 8th May row, per your required logic? Also, Why does the last row have `Qty3` = `10`, given the last row has `0` for `Qty1` and `Qty2`?

Comment: That is right, I have corrected it

Comment: @Boneist Any leads on the solution ?